# Drag and Drop label to panel in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know how to drag and drop in windows application, but I cannot find the mousedown event in the `asp:label` control.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: That sort of thing has to happen on the client side. You need to read up on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As John Saunders already suggest, you need to use client-side script here.

I may advise to use jQuery-UI in conduction with some server-side code. Check the code below: it allows to drag and drop label onto droppable control (only `Panel1` in this example) and save id of that control in value of label's child hidden field. Later on postback in server-side you need to check this new label's parent id value and move label to new parent control if required. To check this code you need to reference jQuery and jQuery-UI libraries files.

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

    $("#<%= Panel1.ClientID %>").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).css({
                "position": "",
                "left": "",
                "top": ""
            });

            $("#<%= Label1Parent.ClientID %>").val(this.id);

            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
});
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" Style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 300px;
    height: 300px;">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1">Some label</asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Label1Parent" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Just some postback button" />
```

Server-side code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label1Parent.Value) && Label1.Parent.ClientID != Label1Parent.Value)
        {
            Label1.Parent.Controls.Remove(Label1);
            var newParent = FindControlRecursive(Page, Label1Parent.Value);
            newParent.Controls.Add(Label1);
        }
    }
}

private static Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string clientID)
{
    if (rootControl.ClientID == clientID) 
        return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        var controlToReturn = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, clientID);

        if (controlToReturn != null) 
            return controlToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```